# Selecting columns from multiple tables and joining onto very large table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a report using a single select statement that joins onto multiple tables and counts the occurrences of an item.

The issue is the tables I am joining to may or may not contain data and the table I am joining from has a large data set.

A simplified example of my problem is:

```
item
-----------------
| id |   name   |
-----------------
|  1 |  item 1  |
|  2 |  item 2  |
|  3 |  item 3  |
|  4 |  item 4  |
|  5 |  item 5  |
|  6 |  item 6  |
|  7 |  item 7  |
|  8 |  item 8  |
|  9 |  item 9  |
-----------------

opened
----------------
| id | item_id |
----------------
|  1 |      1  |
|  2 |      2  |
|  3 |      3  |
|  4 |      3  |
|  5 |      2  |
----------------

closed
----------------
| id | item_id |
----------------
|  1 |      2  |
|  2 |      2  |
|  3 |      5  |
|  4 |      8  |
|  5 |      8  |
----------------
```

both of the following statements are very slow. This is because my item data set has over 2 million records.

```
select i.id, count(o.id) opened, count(c.id) closed
from item i
left join opened o on i.id= o.item_id
left join closed c on i.id= c.item_id
group by i.id;

select i.id, count(o.id) opened, count(c.id) closed
from item i
left join opened o on i.id= o.item_id
left join closed c on i.id= c.item_id
where o.item_id is not null or c.item_id is not null
group by i.id;
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to speed this up. The result I am looking for should be:

```
------------------------
| id | opened | closed |
------------------------
|  1 |      1 |      0 |
|  2 |      2 |      2 |
|  3 |      2 |      0 |
|  5 |      0 |      1 |
|  8 |      0 |      2 |
------------------------
```

Comment: Can you please specify what indexes you have on which columns?

Comment: I would probably start by using "explain" on the queries and see if something obviously wrong is going on. 2 million rows is not an overly large data-set & shouldn't be overly problematic. Might be something simple like a missing index etc. Explain docs are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: I have a primary key index on all of the id columns. I also have an index and foreign key on the item_id columns.